# This type of group of functions is never finitely generated. Proof?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, functions, finitely-generated, infinite-groups

Suppose there is not finitely-generated group $G$ and a finite set $X$.  Then it is impossible that the set of all possible maps $f : X \to G$ is finitely generated.

*Proof.*  If $H = \{ f : X \to G \}$ were finitely generated say by $H = \langle f_1, \dots, f_n\rangle$ with $n \in \Bbb{N}$.  Then for $h \in H$ let $w(h) = $ the smallest word size such that $h = $ a product of $w(h)$ $f_i$ inverses or direct usages.  $w(1) = 0$.  Clearly $w(gh) \leq w(g) + w(h)$.

Then ?

Comment: This is false. What if $X$ has one element?

Comment: I think it's false in general if $G$ is finitely generated. This is just a finite direct product of copies of $G$.

Comment: To be pedantic, what does it mean for a set to be finitely generated?

Comment: @MattSamuel $G$ is not finitely generated, take $G = \Bbb{Q}^{\times}$ please.   The set obviously forms a group under pointwise mult.

Comment: Sure, $\mathbb Q^\times$ is not finitely generated. But you only said that the group is countably infinite. There are certainly countably infinite groups that are finitely generated.

Comment: @MattSamuel fixed

Comment: Do you mean that the group of maps $f\colon X\rightarrow G$ (presumably under pointwise multiplication) is not finitely generated? If $X=\emptyset$, this is false. If $X\neq\emptyset$, this is true.

Comment: @Thorgott how would one go about proving that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** If $X\neq\emptyset$, then there is a surjective homomorphism $G^X\rightarrow G$. Use this to show that if $G^X$ is finitely generated, then so is $G$. (Note: $X$ is not required to be finite)